# Google Maps Api v2 - Detect gps activation

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to locate user using best provider enabled.
When I launch my app with GPS off, the location manager will use network to get user location.

If I turn on my GPS while the app still running, the GPS will not be used because the location manager is listening network provider.

How can I detect the activation/desactivation of GPS and update user location on the map while the location manager is using the network provider ?

#### SOLUTION FOUND

Use locationclient, see this [code example](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html)!

Comment: You wanna detect if GPS is turned on in the settings of the device or if the provider has changed?

Comment: If the network provider is used, I want to know when user activate the gps to use it

Comment: solution found thx to you all, I had a link in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line to detect if the GPS was enabled by the user:

```
yourLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

It will return true if it's enabled or ortherwise false.

But as MaciejGórski said, do yourself a favor and use the [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). You will never ask yourself questions like this anymore.

Comment: I use this line when app starts to define whether I use network or gps provider. My problem is when the app starts with GPS off and the user turn it on while app is running

Comment: There is no other way to detect if the user did the switch. Check this in onStart / onResume. To notice it if the user comes back to the app

Comment: Ok, pause and resume do the job perfectly except if the user. But how to do when the user use the settings menu and activate gps ? (slide on top screen)

Comment: Well, if the user pulls the notification bar and enables GPS (like on Samsung devices) things will be complicated. Like I said there is no way to be informed about the GPS enabling / disabling. And because of that reason you should consider to use the LocationClient, because this API will take care about that things.

Comment: Thx for all answers, I use now location thx to a code snippet (I had in first post)

Answer (score 1):

Use new [`LocationClient`](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) fused provider. It does all the hard work for you and listens for all providers when they are enabled.